# Python XML element tree empties xml file on system power failure

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, elementtree

I have a Python 3 app that uses Element Tree module to parse and write data to an xml file periodically (once every 10 seconds).

The app runs on a small Raspberry system that is almost never shut down properly. It's always on and in case of power failure it shuts down. 
Sometimes, when the system reboots and the python app starts, it finds an empty xml file. The file is still on the filesystem but it's completely empty. 
I think that it happens when ET is writing the XML tree on file and the system loses the power supply. I found that ET automatically closes the write stream on finish. Is that correct?

My only idea to avoid this is to periodically make a mirror copy of my file and bring it up in case that the main xml file is found empty...but is there a better way to solve my problem?

To reply to Parfait:

```
class XML_timer_prog:
    def __init__(self):
        self.path = root_dir + 'static/XML/current/'
        self.filename = 'timer_prog.xml'
        self.tree = ''
        self.root = ''

    def open(self):
        self.tree = ET.parse(self.path + self.filename)
        self.root = self.tree.getroot()
        return self.root
        self.root = self.open()

    def update(self, timer, timer_id ):
        for t in self.root.iter('timer'):
           #here update some entries

        self.tree.write(self.path + self.filename, encoding="UTF-8", xml_declaration=True)
        return 1
```

Comment: Please show code to contextualize your setup especially `write` section.

Comment: Don't periodically make a copy but _always_ write the new/changed data into a new file and rename that to the actual filename after writing.  Depending on the file system this completely solves the problem or minimizes the time window where something can go wrong.

Comment: @BlackJack: thanks a lot I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what BlackJack said, I would import the time module and add a variable equal to the name you want to give your file + the date and time of writing + the file extension. Something like this:

import time

''' actual code here '''

variable_name = 'name_of_file' + time.strftime('%Y%m%d') + '.file_extension'

Since you are writing every 10 seconds, adding a %S might be more accurate, too.

Answer (score 0):

BlackJack solution worked fine for me, now my write calls are like this:

```
self.tree.write(self.path + self.temp_file, encoding="UTF-8" xml_declaration=True)
shutil.copy(self.path + self.temp_file, self.path + self.filename)
```

Where the self.filename variable is the final XML file. I tried several times and lost no XML at the moment